# Popping not sufficient to remove a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am experiencing an issue and I believe it's due to me incorrectly removing my view. I will try to explain and hope all can follow. 
I have a `UISplitview` app which essentially has two views. The main detail view, and a view which is essentially a map. Upon selecting a certain string in the table this code is called (this code is in the detailview but the rainObject is passed in from a `UIViewController`.

```
-(void)setReceivedRainObject:(id)receivedRainObject{
    if ([receivedRainObject isEqualToString:@"Test"]){
        mapViewController *mapView=[[mapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"mapViewController" bundle:nil location:0];
        [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:NO];
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapView animated:NO];
    }
}
```

So the above code loads my map fine in the detailscreen as expected.
However, when I click the first option (test) from the left view controller, it calls a new view controller (viewcontroller2 with a row named test2) and that second controller calls a third( viewcontroller3 with a row named test3)
On the `viewDidDisappear` of viewcontoller3 and in the `viewWillAppear` of test I have this code

```
 [self.detailViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

So when I drill down to viewcontroller, when I click the backbutton, it pops off one map, and when testview loads it pops the second. leaving my detail view showing exactly how I started.
However, I've noticed that if I clicked the "test" button twice, and try to go back, there is an "extra screen" that was supposed to be remove with pop. Would like to know how to remove this mass of views or to stop the program from adding so many.
 Thanks

Comment: You get the extra screen because you have pushed mapView twice - once for each touch on the test button.  I am not sure what navigation you are trying to achieve, but it doesn't sound right to me.  It sounds like your button should just present a new view controller in the detail view, not push it.  Calling `popViewController` in a `ViewWillAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` is certainly ringing alarm bells for me.  If navigation through your app doesn't use a stack of views, don't use a navigation controller

Comment: @Paulw11 my button has to show the view with the map when i click it, how else can this be done without pushing. Whats the difference between  presenting and pushing. Secondly, when I am done with it isnt poping what you do to get rid of it?

Comment: You don't have to use a navigation controller.  Are you using storyboards?  If so you can just create a replace segue between your base detailviewcontroller and the new one, give it a name and then trigger it with `[detailViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:]`

Comment: popping is what you do with a navigationcontroller as it is a stack of views, but it is not the only way of managing your views in an app, and if your app isn't naturally navigated as a stack of views then it can just get in the way

Comment: @Paulw11 Well my first view that loads is a storyboard but i didnt go n with it i just loaded the second view i needed from a nib. I will look into the storyboards then. Will report back

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi, I tried to use storyboard but that didnt seem to want to work for me(since I have never looked into using it before so i need to start on square one before i can directly implement it).
However i used this line [self.detailViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; . Does it remove all the views i added? say if i clicked the button 10 times? does it remove all of them? or retain them and just show the root

Comment: It will pop to the root view controller no matter how deep the stack. The views won't be retained by the navigation controller. Whether they are actually released depends on whether any other object is still holding a reference. You can watch the memory graph in XCode while your app is running or use the Instruments tool to monitor memory usage and see if the objects are "sticking around"

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
mapViewController *mapView=[[mapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"mapViewController" bundle:nil location:0];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapView animated:YES];
```

to navigate through the view controllers.